# How can I sort digit names in numerical order in Javascript using standard array methods?

Tags: javascript, sorting

How can I sort digit names in numerical order in Javascript using standard array methods?

Examples:

```
[] =>
[]

[ 'nine', 'one' ] =>
[ 'one',  'nine' ]

[ 'one', 'two', 'three' ] =>
[ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]

[ 'nine',  'eight', 'nine', 'eight' ] =>
[ 'eight', 'eight', 'nine', 'nine']

[ 'one',  'one', 'one', 'zero' ] =>
[ 'zero', 'one', 'one', 'one' ]
```

Comment: please add the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you don't know how to even start, that's why you didn't even try.

Anyway, here is one of approches, how it can be done:

```js
const input = ['nine','eight','nine','eight', 'one','two','three']

const digitsComparator = (a, b) => {
  const mapper = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four',
                  'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
  return mapper.indexOf(a) - mapper.indexOf(b) 
}

const res = input.sort(digitsComparator)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
arr = [ 'nine','eight','nine','eight'];

const mapper = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four',
    'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

return arr.sort((a, b) => mapper.indexOf(a) - mapper.indexOf(b))
```

Comment: I don't get it. It looks the same as the other answer with a few things moved around.